# Get the size of the file(in bytes) currently written by the StreamWriter

Tags: c#, stream

I am working with files and stream. I want to roll the file when it extends its limit. So my question is how to get the number of bytes written by the `StreamWriter` so I can compare with the file limit and if it extends the limit, move to the next file.

```
class RollingFile
{
    ...

    int GetBytesWritten(StreamWriter sw)
    {
        // Do something here to get the size of the file which is being written by the stream
    }

    // and, my all write operations goes here.
    void AppendMessage(StreamWriter writer, string message)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess Google didn't turn up [`.Position`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position(v=vs.110).aspx) (assuming you're writing sequentially to a previously empty/non-existent file).

Comment: The Position property does not keep track of the number of bytes from the stream that have been consumed, skipped, or both. - Perhaps that is the problem with position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the StreamWriter doesn't write immediately. 
You can try using `writer.BaseStream.Length` but it could throw an error, so you will need to flush data first `writer.AutoFlush = true` or `writer.Flush()`.